# FactoryGirl defining an object which must have at least one other object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a two models `Project` and `ProjectImage`. A `project` must have at least one `project_image` to be valid. This is set up fine in my application but when it comes to testing, I'm unsure how to approach it.

I have my project factory:

```
factory :project do
  title { Faker::Lorem.word(5) }
  intro { Faker::Lorem.word(5) }

  association :user, factory: :user
end
```

And my project_image factory.

```
factory :project_image do
  image { File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'sampleimages/projects', '*')).sample) }

  association :project, factory: :project
  association :user, factory: :user
end
```

Obviously as is, my project factory is invalid because it needs to have at least one image. So I thought it required an association, but, that would just create a circular dependency. They depend on each other, so I'm sure how to create one without the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can hack it this way

```
factory :project do
  title { Faker::Lorem.word(5) }
  intro { Faker::Lorem.word(5) }

  association :user, factory: :user

  after(:build) do |project|
    FactoryGirl.build(:project_image, project: project)
  end
end
```

PS you can define factories a little bit easier

```
factory :project_image do
  image { File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'sampleimages/projects', '*')).sample) }

  project
  user
end
```

PPS if answer directly on your question

> So I thought it required an association, but, that would just create a circular dependency

You can pass an attribute(s) to factory and it will use it instead of what you define in file factory. Example: you need a project with 3 pictures

```
project = FactoryGirl.create(:project) # this project has one picture created in factory
FactoryGirl.create_list(:project_image, 2, project: project) # this will create two pictures for existed project

project.reload # you need update local varial to fetch new records from DB
project.project_images.size # => 3
```

Comment: did you try build/create records through factories in console? Place factory_girl gem in test/development group, run console in sandbox mode `rails c -s`, perform `require factory_girl_rails` and try to debug objects, for example `project = FactoryGirl.build(:project); project.project_images; project.valid?`

Comment: one more idea why you have still problem is: try this code in `after(:build)` `project.project_images = [FactoryGirl.build(:project_image)]`